# How can I resolve thenReturn() may be missing exception in junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Can someone please help what to do to resolve below mentioned exception
When stubbing below mentioned line

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(customerRepository.save(customerProduct))
```

Suggest me correct execution here

```
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
```

Examples of correct stubbing:

```
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

Hints:

```
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Mockito.doNothing().when(customerRepository).save(customerProduct)`?

Answer (score 1):

[The mockito docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.6.28/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doNothing--) tell `doNothing()` method should be used like this:

```java
doNothing().when(mock).method()
```

So in your case you may want to try this:

```java
Mockito.doNothing().when(customerRepository)
    .save(customerProduct)
```